# Password generator. Display 8 non-duplicate passwords in ListBox

Tags: vb.net

good day. There is a code for generating passwords.

```vb
  Dim i_keys As Integer
        Dim numKeys As Integer = 8

        Dim chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*"
        Dim stringChars = New Char(7) {}
        Dim random = New Random()

        For i As Integer = 0 To stringChars.Length - 1
            stringChars(i) = chars.Chars(random.Next(chars.Length))
        Next i

        Dim finalString = New String(stringChars)

        For i_keys = 1 To numKeys
            ListBox1.Items.Add(finalString)
        Next
```

But as a result, I get the following:

```
0EbrQ4Pf
0EbrQ4Pf
0EbrQ4Pf
0EbrQ4Pf
0EbrQ4Pf
0EbrQ4Pf
0EbrQ4Pf
0EbrQ4Pf
```

Tell me how you can make it so that you get 10 random (not repeated) passwords at the output.

Comment: You're only setting 'finalString' once, so it's always going to have the same value. You need to expand the For i_keys loop to encompass the other for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need the last loop to encompass a bit more code.

```
Dim i_keys As Integer
Dim numKeys As Integer = 8

Dim chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*"
Dim random = New Random()

For i_keys = 1 To numKeys
    Dim stringChars = New Char(7) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To stringChars.Length - 1
        stringChars(i) = chars.Chars(random.Next(chars.Length))
    Next i

    Dim finalString = New String(stringChars)

    ListBox1.Items.Add(finalString)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

See inline comments.

The first method employs the .net random number generator.

The second method the .net `Guid` which stands for Global Unique Identifier.

I think either of these methods would be adequate for your purposes. Since we are truncating the `Guid`, the guaranteed uniqueness dissapears.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*"
    Dim random = New Random()
    Dim charsLength = chars.Length 'Resove this once outside the loop
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    For p = 0 To 9 'Number of passwords to put into ListBox is 10
        For i = 0 To 7 'password length is 8
            sb.Append(chars(random.Next(charsLength))) 'Next
        Next
        lst.Add(sb.ToString)
        sb.Clear()
    Next
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lst.ToArray) 'Update the user interface once after the loop
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    For i = 0 To 9 'Number of passwords
        Dim pWord = Guid.NewGuid().ToString.Substring(0, 8)
        lst.Add(pWord)
    Next
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lst.ToArray)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your password generator is outside of the loop. This code is not very elegant but here you go (including a check if the password is unique):

```
       Dim i_keys As Integer
        Dim numKeys As Integer = 10

        Dim chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*"
        Dim stringChars = New Char(7) {}
        Dim random = New Random()
           

        Dim finalString = New String(stringChars)

        For i_keys = 1 To numKeys

             For i As Integer = 0 To stringChars.Length - 1
                  stringChars(i) = chars.Chars(random.Next(chars.Length))
              Next i
            finalString = New String(stringChars)
            If  ListBox1.Items.Contains(finalString) then
                   i_keys  = i_keys  -1
            else
               ListBox1.Items.Add(finalString)
            End if
          
        Next
```

Please try using datatypes like List(Of String) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The work can be done in one line of LINQ, using Enumerable.Range and Select in place of the loops.

```vb
Dim numKeys = 8
Dim numChars = 8
Dim chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*"
Dim rnd = New Random()
Dim result = Enumerable.Range(0, numKeys).Select(Function(i) New String(Enumerable.Range(0, numChars).Select(Function(j) chars(rnd.Next(chars.Length))).ToArray()))
ListBox1.DataSource = result.ToArray()
```